# I am trying to pull data from multiple table in oracle. My current code is pulling the correct data but it is creating duplicate records

Tags: sql, oracle

My SQL code is creating duplicates in the results. If an applicant has more than one reg date, it will create those amounts for each reg date there is. Instead of just the reg date it belongs to.
If there is a reg date for 5/1/22 and 6/1/22 and an amount for 5/1/22. It will show up for both reg dates instead of just the one it belongs to.

```
SELECT b.applicant_id,
       b.program_code,
       b.last_name,
       b.first_name,
       a.username,
       b.region_code,
       b.reg_date,
       b.status_cd,
       s.first_name AS "Staff",
       s.last_name  AS "Staff2",
       b.exit_date,
       ss.program_code,
       ss.support_service_amt,
       ss.expenditure_begin_date,
       ss.expenditure_end_date   
  FROM bres_reg b
  LEFT JOIN support_service ss
    ON ss.applicant_id = b.applicant_id
  LEFT JOIN staff s
    ON s.ID = b.case_manager_staff_id                    
  LEFT JOIN applicant a
    ON b.applicant_id = a.ID
 WHERE ss.program_code = 'BRES'
```

Comment: Add sample data, expected result and result you get

Comment: It sounds like you are missing a date-related join condition, but without knowing more about your table structures and data it's hard to say which join or what it should include.